# In pyspark, how do you add/concat a string to a column?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to add a string to an existing column. For example, `df['col1']` has values as `'1', '2', '3'` etc and I would like to concat string `'000'` on the left of `col1` so I can get a column (new or replace the old one doesn't matter) as `'0001', '0002', '0003'`.

I thought I should use `df.withColumn('col1', '000'+df['col1'])` but of course it does not work since pyspark dataframe are immutable?

This should be an easy task but i didn't find anything online. Hope someone can give me some help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, col, lit


df.select(concat(col("firstname"), lit(" "), col("lastname"))).show(5)
+------------------------------+
|concat(firstname,  , lastname)|
+------------------------------+
|                Emanuel Panton|
|              Eloisa Cayouette|
|                   Cathi Prins|
|             Mitchel Mozdzierz|
|               Angla Hartzheim|
+------------------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions

Comment: Hi Steven, Thank you for your help! I think your solution works for my case and i did a little modification to suit my case as df = df.withColumn('col1', concat(lit("000"), col("col1"))) .   In addition, is using lit the only way to add constant to modify the column values in pyspark? Because in pandas, i would just use df['col1']='000' + df['col1'] but not sure if in pyspark, there will be multiple ways to achieve it!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question posed by OP, it just shows how to concatenate two columns.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and I do not find lit in it. What is the alternative for python 2.7 for the same issue?

Answer (score 16):

Another option here is to use [`pyspark.sql.functions.format_string()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.format_string) which allows you to use [C `printf` style formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Here's an example where the values in the column are integers.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,), (3,), (10,), (100,)], ["col1"])
df.withColumn("col2", f.format_string("%03d", "col1")).show()
#+----+----+
#|col1|col2|
#+----+----+
#|   1| 001|
#|   2| 002|
#|   3| 003|
#|  10| 010|
#| 100| 100|
#+----+----+
```

Here the format `"%03d"` means print an integer number left padded with up to 3 zeros. This is why the `10` gets mapped to `010` and `100` does not change at all.

Or if you wanted to add exactly 3 zeros in the front:

```python
df.withColumn("col2", f.format_string("000%d", "col1")).show()
#+----+------+
#|col1|  col2|
#+----+------+
#|   1|  0001|
#|   2|  0002|
#|   3|  0003|
#|  10| 00010|
#| 100|000100|
#+----+------+
```

Comment: This is the answer a little more general and the examples address the exact question, however I found the previous one more useful for what I was looking for when I found this question. Variety is gold!

Answer (score 4):

I did this is PySpark in Databricks (Azure).
Lets assume you have a column named 'column_source' in your data frame `df` with values `1,2,3`

| column_source |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Then you can use below code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('column_modified', F.concat(F.lit("000"), F.col('column_source')))
```

output:

| column_source | column_modified |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001 |
| 2 | 0002 |
| 3 | 0003 |