# Pyspark - Round time represented as an integer to nearest quarter hour (15 minutes)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rounding

I am working on a dataframe on Pyspark. One column is composed by integer value corresponding to time:

```python
data.select('TIME').show(4)
+------------------+
|TIME              |
+------------------+
|               925|
|              2205|
|              2205|
|              2205|
+------------------+
```

I would like to round this time to the closest value with a time step of 15 minutes, in order to obtain:

```python
+------------------+
|TIME_15_MIN_STEP  |
+------------------+
|               930|
|              2200|
|              2200|
|              2200|
+------------------+
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I guess for 925 that the algorithm should check if 925 is closer to 930 or to 915, that are the closest multiple values of 15. I don't understand why 2205 has to become 2200? 2205 is already a multiple of 15, which is the logic behind this rounding?

Comment: Because they represent time (2205 = 22:05 = 10:05 pm) .

Comment: Are there some specific reasons for representing time as an integer (925) instead of a string ("09:25")? It is handy to represent time as an integer if it is a timestamp (e.g. milliseconds from epoch) or as a string  if it is a hour or a date (and many operations can be performed in both situations)

Comment: Go with UDF. 1st step transform this time to normal `datetime` and then use it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723150/rounding-up-to-nearest-30-minutes-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this without using a `udf` is to first convert your integer column into a dummy timestamp, and then do pretty much the same thing as outlined in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50453285/5858851) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362116/round-timestamp-to-nearest-30-second). Finally convert the result back into an integer of the desired format.

**More thorough example data**

I created an example with some more variability to demonstrate that this method is working properly.

```python
data = sqlCtx.createDataFrame([(925,), (2205,), (2210,), (2242,), (2255,)], ["TIME"])
data.show()
#+----+
#|TIME|
#+----+
#| 925|
#|2205|
#|2210|
#|2242|
#|2255|
#+----+
```

**Converting Integer Column To dummy Timestamp**

To convert the integer hour-minute column into a timestamp, we first use [`pyspark.sql.functions.format_string()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.format_string) to [add leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49696839/5858851) to the time when appropriate. Next we concatenate a dummy date (I used `"2018-01-01"`) with the converted time, and add `":00"` at the end (for seconds).

```python
data = data.withColumn("time_string", f.format_string("%04d", f.col("TIME")))\
    .withColumn(
        "time_string",
        f.concat_ws(
            ":",
            f.array(
                [
                    f.substring(
                        "time_string",
                        1,
                        2
                    ),
                    f.substring(
                        "time_string",
                        3,
                        2
                    ),
                    f.lit("00")
                ]
            )
        )
    )\
    .withColumn("time_string", f.concat(f.lit("2018-01-01 "), f.col("time_string")))

data.show()
#+----+-------------------+
#|TIME|        time_string|
#+----+-------------------+
#| 925|2018-01-01 09:25:00|
#|2205|2018-01-01 22:05:00|
#|2210|2018-01-01 22:10:00|
#|2242|2018-01-01 22:42:00|
#|2255|2018-01-01 22:55:00|
#+----+-------------------+
```

**Compute how many minutes to offset the timestamp**

Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.minute()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.minute) to get the minute from the dummy timestamp. We divide by 15, round, and then multiply by 15 to get the "new" minute. (This logic is explained in more detail in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50453285/5858851).)

```python
data = data.withColumn("minute", f.minute("time_string"))\
    .withColumn("new_minute", f.round(f.col("minute")/15)*15)\
    .withColumn("minute_add", f.col("new_minute") - f.col("minute"))\

data.show()
#+----+-------------------+------+----------+----------+
#|TIME|        time_string|minute|new_minute|minute_add|
#+----+-------------------+------+----------+----------+
#| 925|2018-01-01 09:25:00|    25|      30.0|       5.0|
#|2205|2018-01-01 22:05:00|     5|       0.0|      -5.0|
#|2210|2018-01-01 22:10:00|    10|      15.0|       5.0|
#|2242|2018-01-01 22:42:00|    42|      45.0|       3.0|
#|2255|2018-01-01 22:55:00|    55|      60.0|       5.0|
#+----+-------------------+------+----------+----------+
```

**Add offset in seconds, convert back to integer**

Multiply the `minute_add` column by 60 to get the offset in seconds. Add this to the `time_string` to get the "new" time.

```python
data = data.withColumn(
        "new_time",
        f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp("time_string") + f.col("minute_add")*60)
    )\
    .withColumn(
        "NEW_TIME",
        f.format_string("%02d%02d", f.hour("new_time"), f.minute("new_time")).cast("int")
    )
data.select("TIME", "NEW_TIME").show()
#+----+--------+
#|TIME|NEW_TIME|
#+----+--------+
#| 925|     930|
#|2205|    2200|
#|2210|    2215|
#|2242|    2245|
#|2255|    2300|
#+----+--------+
```

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman. This is such a great answer, although the one below it looks good too.

Answer (score 4):

A nicer way to group by 15 minutes is to use `pyspark.sql.functions.window` on your timestamp:

```
df = df \
   .groupBy(F.window("timestamp", "15 minutes")) \
   .withColumn("timestamp", F.col("window.start"))
```

See documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window)