# Round timestamp to nearest 30 second

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a column in a `DF` and it contains `timestamp` in format ( yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss). I need to round `timestamp` to nearest 30 seconds.

```
old column                   desired column
2016-02-09 19:31:02          2016-02-09 19:31:00  
2016-02-09 19:31:35          2016-02-09 19:31:30
2016-02-09 19:31:52          2016-02-09 19:32:00
2016-02-09 19:31:28          2016-02-09 19:31:30
```

Is it possible to do that in Pyspark ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using spark verson 1.5+, you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.second()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.second) to get the seconds from your timestamp column.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.withColumn("second", f.second("old_timestamp")).show()
#+-------------------+------+
#|      old_timestamp|second|
#+-------------------+------+
#|2016-02-09 19:31:02|     2|
#|2016-02-09 19:31:35|    35|
#|2016-02-09 19:31:52|    52|
#|2016-02-09 19:31:28|    28|
#+-------------------+------+
```

Once you have the seconds part you can take this number, divide by 30, round it, and multiply by 30 to get the "new" second.

```python
df.withColumn("second", f.second("old_timestamp"))\
    .withColumn("new_second", f.round(f.col("second")/30)*30)\
    .show()
#+-------------------+------+----------+
#|      old_timestamp|second|new_second|
#+-------------------+------+----------+
#|2016-02-09 19:31:02|     2|       0.0|
#|2016-02-09 19:31:35|    35|      30.0|
#|2016-02-09 19:31:52|    52|      60.0|
#|2016-02-09 19:31:28|    28|      30.0|
#+-------------------+------+----------+
```

From the "new" second, we can compute an offset in seconds, which when added to the original timestamp will produce the desired "rounded" timestamps.

```python
df.withColumn("second", f.second("old_timestamp"))\
    .withColumn("new_second", f.round(f.col("second")/30)*30)\
    .withColumn("add_seconds", f.col("new_second") - f.col("second"))\
    .show()
#+-------------------+------+----------+-----------+
#|      old_timestamp|second|new_second|add_seconds|
#+-------------------+------+----------+-----------+
#|2016-02-09 19:31:02|     2|       0.0|       -2.0|
#|2016-02-09 19:31:35|    35|      30.0|       -5.0|
#|2016-02-09 19:31:52|    52|      60.0|        8.0|
#|2016-02-09 19:31:28|    28|      30.0|        2.0|
#+-------------------+------+----------+-----------+
```

As we can see, a negative number in this column means that the original time has to be rounded down. A positive number will increase the time.

In order to add this time to the original timestamp, first convert it to a unix timestamp using [`pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp). After the addition, convert the result back to a timestamp using [`pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime).

Putting this all together (condensing the intermediate steps):

```python
df.withColumn(
        "add_seconds",
        (f.round(f.second("old_timestamp")/30)*30) - f.second("old_timestamp")
    )\
    .withColumn(
        "new_timestamp",
        f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp("old_timestamp") + f.col("add_seconds"))
    )\
    .drop("add_seconds")\
    .show()
#+-------------------+-------------------+
#|      old_timestamp|      new_timestamp|
#+-------------------+-------------------+
#|2016-02-09 19:31:02|2016-02-09 19:31:00|
#|2016-02-09 19:31:35|2016-02-09 19:31:30|
#|2016-02-09 19:31:52|2016-02-09 19:32:00|
#|2016-02-09 19:31:28|2016-02-09 19:31:30|
#+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: thank you for your effort! I have done it in a different way.

Comment: i converted time to epoch in (seconds)  and then round the resultant number to 30 after that converted the new epochs to human readable date

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I modified it slightly to round to the nearest 30 minute interval and it works beautifully.