# select columns and add fixed width space between columns and save to fixedWidth File in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to select few columns from a DF.

Between the columns I need to add different spaces as end user wants fixed width file (but not sure about the few columns in future). So some fixed width space needs to be added between.
I need to save this file as text file without header as FixedWidth file.

My output string should look like below

`aaa   bbb   ccc   ddd`

where aaa, bbb... are columns values selected from DF and with 3 spaces added in between.

Can anyone please help here

Comment: Do you want to merge multiple column to one column with space between the values

Comment: you can concat all columns into one string column with fixed length and write the output

Comment: yes, I want something like in SQL , -- select col1,"  ",col2,"   ",col3 from table -- this result to be stored in one fixed width string

Answer (score 1):

This is pyspark
[In pyspark, how do you add/concat a string to a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397966/in-pyspark-how-do-you-add-concat-a-string-to-a-column)

But in Scala it is almost the same:

`df.select(concat(col("firstColumn"), lit("   "), 
                  col("secondColumn"), lit("   "), 
                  col("thirdColumn"))).show()`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to work with RDDs if you save output as a text file. Here is my solution for pyspark

```
>>> data = sc.parallelize([
...     ('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'),
...     ('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'),
...     ('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd')])
>>> columns = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> 
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
>>> 
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd|
|aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd|
|aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd|
+---+---+---+---+

>>> 
>>> df.registerTempTable("table1")
>>> 
>>> table1 = spark.sql("select concat(a,'   ', b,'   ',c, '   ', d) col from table1")
>>> 
>>> table1.show()
+--------------------+
|                 col|
+--------------------+
|aaa   bbb   ccc  ...|
|aaa   bbb   ccc  ...|
|aaa   bbb   ccc  ...|
+--------------------+

>>> 
>>> rdd = table1.rdd.map(lambda x: "".join([str(i) for i in x]))
>>> 
>>> rdd.collect()
['aaa   bbb   ccc   ddd', 'aaa   bbb   ccc   ddd', 'aaa   bbb   ccc   ddd']
>>> 
>>> rdd.saveAsTextFile("/yourpath")
```